# SOAP UI - Set Proxy Settings Using -t in CMD Execution

Tags: xml, command-line, soapui

I am getting nowhere with the documentation on this topic.

So far, I know the execution command is "-t" for setting the proxy settings, BUT, I cannot get the proxy settings to actually be set.

In other words, the command line query looks like this:

```
"cmd /C CD  
C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin & testrunner.bat 
-c""TestCase"" ""SOAP_QUERY.XML"" 
-S 
-P""UserName=UsernameTest"" 
-P""Password=PasswordTest"" 
-t""autoProxy_TrueOrFalse=False"" 
-t""activateProxy_TrueOrFalse=True"" 
-t""proxy_Host=ProxyAddress"" 
-t""proxy_Port=ProxyPort"" 
-t""proxy_Username=ProxyUsername"" 
-t""proxy_Username=ProxyPassword"" 
-P""OutPutDumpFileLocation=OutPut.XML"" 
-e ""https://EndPoint"" 
-r > ""ExecutionLog.Txt"
```

Obviously, the values I provided are not those text values - I put the actual details in there. Example, ProxyPort could be 8080.

I know the XML for the settings of the proxy looks like this:

```
 <con:soapui-settings xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@autoProxy">XYZ</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@enableProxy">XYZ</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@host">XYZ</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@port">XYZ</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@username">XYZ</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@password">XYZ</con:setting>
  </con:soapui-settings>
```

BUT, I don't know if this goes into the query OR directly in the settings file and then you can parametrize it like this:

```
<con:soapui-settings xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@autoProxy">${#Project#autoProxy_TrueOrFalse}</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@enableProxy">${#Project#activateProxy_TrueOrFalse}</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@host">${#Project#proxy_Host}</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@port">${#Project#proxy_Port}</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@username">${#Project#proxy_Username}</con:setting>
     <con:setting id="ProxySettings@password">${#Project#proxy_Password}</con:setting>
  </con:soapui-settings>
```

I even tried to modify the command line query like:

```
"cmd /C CD  
C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin & testrunner.bat 
-c""TestCase"" ""SOAP_QUERY.XML"" 
-S 
-P""UserName=UsernameTest"" 
-P""Password=PasswordTest"" 
-t""ProxySettings@autoProxy=False""
-t""ProxySettings@enableProxy=True""
-t""ProxySettings@host=ProxyAddress""
-t""ProxySettings@port=ProxyPort""
-t""ProxySettings@username=ProxyUsername""
-t""ProxySettings@password=ProxyPassword"" 
-P""OutPutDumpFileLocation=OutPut.XML""
-e ""https://EndPoint"" 
-r > ""ExecutionLog.Txt"
```

Please if anyone has experience in creating this command line execution PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programmatically with Groovy like this:

```
    import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI
    import com.eviware.soapui.settings.ProxySettings

    SoapUI.settings.setString(ProxySettings.HOST, proxyServer)
    SoapUI.settings.setString(ProxySettings.PORT, proxyPort)
    SoapUI.settings.setString(ProxySettings.USERNAME, proxyUser)
    SoapUI.settings.setString(ProxySettings.PASSWORD, proxyPwd)
    SoapUI.settings.setString(ProxySettings.ENABLE_PROXY, "true")
    SoapUI.saveSettings()
    SoapUI.updateProxyFromSettings()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, really appreciate it. I am not familiar with Groovy - in fact I only self-taught myself SOAP UI about 2 weeks ago.. So I have no clue where this should be placed nor how I get the parameters into the script you've provided. Could you perhaps elaborate a little more please?

Comment: @Eitel Dagnin Sure. The simplest is to make a script like this: In your Project -> TestSuite -> Test Case -> Test Steps make a new Groovy Script test step. Call it setUp. Put the code in there. If you run it, it will execute whatever code you have in the script. The code in my answer sort of explains itself. HTH. If you are going to be using SoapUI a lot, it will really benefit you to learn Groovy. It can be used for general programming too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Will definitely need to read a bit more into Groovy... Could you perhaps tell me, 1-Does the Groovy Script run BEFORE the SOAP Query and 2-Can I pass parameters to the Groovy Script in the same way I pass parameters to the SOAP Script? I have put the Groovy Script in the same TEST CASE as the SOAP Script..

Comment: If I remember correctly, test steps in a test case run in alphabetical order, so in my project I have groovy steps called AAA-setUp and ZZZ-tearDown. If you are talking about properties as parameters, then yes. e.g. setting a prop: `testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("userName", "peter")` and retrieve it elsewhere:
`def username = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("userName")`

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into this over the weekend. :)

Comment: Sorry I took a while to get back to this, but the solution worked well, Thank you :)